# How to solve the inequality $x^a-ax\le b$?

Tags: inequality

$$x^{a}-ax\leqslant b$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants satisfying $a>1>b$ . In addition, we have $0<x<1$.

Comment: The inequality does not hold when $b<0$. Take for example $x=\frac{1}{2}, a=2, b=-1$, then $x^a-ax=-\frac{3}{4}>-1=b$.

Comment: @IvanLoh: what if $x=1$?

Comment: Your question specified $x<1$. Anyway, the above was just an example for illustration. To clarify, there are some solutions for $x$ when $1-a<b$, but when $b \leq 1-a$, there are no solutions.

Comment: Oh,sorry, I forgot. I think there are solutions when $1-a<b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\gt1$ and $0\lt x\lt 1$, then $x^a\lt x\lt ax$ hence $x^a-ax\lt0$. If $b\geqslant0$, every $x$ in $[0,1]$ is such that $x^a-ax\leqslant b$.

Another obvious remark is that $x\mapsto x^a-ax$ is decreasing from $0$ at $x=0$ to $1-a$ at $x=1$ hence, if $b\leqslant1-a$, there is no solution in $[0,1)$, while if $1-a\lt b\lt0$, the set of solutions is  an interval $[x_b,1)$, where $x_b$ solves $x^a-ax=b$.

Comment: Then. You. Should. Have. Mentioned. It. In. The. Question.

Comment: I know, but there is no such constraint. I think we should solve this inequality in these two cases.

Comment: There is no solution when $b=1-a$, as we cannot have $x=1$. Maybe you should edit that into your answer.

Comment: @IvanLoh Yup. Thanks.